# How to create a "clicking effect" on a 3d-object (3d-cube) in Unity3d?

Tags: animation, button, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a 3d-object (cube), which I want to use as a button. I've written the code in order to detect, if the cube was pressed but it doesn't look like it was pressed, since it lacks the "clicking animation". How can I create a clicking animation on my 3d-object ?

Comment: Sounds like you can just move the button on one of its local axes?

Answer (score 2):

You can scale it down a tiny bit once click happen. For example:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    this.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
}
```

Then after click scale it back to the original size.

Answer (score 2):

A good idea is to play an aninimation which skrinks the cube a bit and releases it immediately afterwards. The handler code you want to execute on a click might block the game loop, e.g. when you load a level. Then it might be useful to load the level aysnchronously to be able to see the animation. Or you execute the handler code after the animation. Or you play the scale down animation on the press event and the scale up animation on the release event.

Technically you can use the build in animation editor, the Update() method, start a coroutine or use the assets iTween or HOTween.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html

Let me know if you like the idea or questions arise.

Comment: It's not really a game but a part of the app using vuforia SDK. After image recognition I've added some cubes as buttons and I want them to be clickable. I want user to understand that: "Hey, you can press these cubes. These are not just boxes, but buttons". I want them to have an animation as a simple 2d-button, which is clicked, or at least something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Unity makes it easier now to do this using Unity Canvas UI. Instead of real 3d buttons, you could place a canvas UI in world space at the location where you want the buttons. Add a UI Panel to the canvas then add a UI Button.

Now, you have out of the box several clicking effects. The default it color tint, but you can choose sprite swap, or animation.

If you do want animation, when you select button animation it will create an animator for you. Click on your UI button Game Object in the scene hierarchy and open the animation window. You can choose Pressed animation from the drop down, and press RECORD button, then edit your buttons scale, say make it 0.75 for x,y,z. Now when you click on the button it will animate a cool scale down for you.

Sorry, I know that is a lot of information dumped! But you will find it pretty great once you start working with it in world space.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into iTween (free on Unity Asset store).

Its very easy to use and you can produce some nice looking animations.

Answer (score 1):

you can scale it when pressed or just change the color a little bit. On mouse up, rescale or recolor it.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.05, 0.05 , 0);
    //or
    transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color += new Color(40,40,40);
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.05, 0.05 , 0);
    //or
    transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color -= new Color(40,40,40);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement your button using new Event system of unity. Here are the functions you can implement :

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
       //it is the function when you hover your mouse to the object
       //You can change the color of your object to make your users
       //understand that it is not just a cube but also a clickable item
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
      //You can revert your color back to its original
    }

    public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        //You can play with local scale as suggested by other answers here
    }
    public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
       // Revert back the changes you made at onPointerDown
    }

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
         //Use here for operations when your button is clicked
    }

}
```